# OpenGL/TK TexSubImage2D can't modify transparent pixel

Tags: c#, opengl, transparency, textures, opentk

I have loaded in an image with this method:

```
    public static int LoadTexture(string file)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(file);

        int tex;

        GL.GenTextures(1, out tex);
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, tex);

        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, data.Width, data.Height, 0,
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0);

        bitmap.UnlockBits(data);

        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat);

        Console.WriteLine("[ImageDisplay] Loaded image: " + file);

        return tex;
    }
```

I need to modify pixels within this image, so i have used this:

```
GL.TexSubImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, X, Y, 1, 1, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Rgb, PixelType.UnsignedInt, new uint[] { 0xFFFF0000 });
```

My problem, is that only non-transparent pixels change to red, the transparent pixels do not change at all.

How could i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Rgb, PixelType.UnsignedInt, new uint[] { 0xFFFF0000 }
```

The [pixel transfer format](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_format) you state is `GL_RGB`. That means 3 components: red, green, and blue, in that order.

The [pixel transfer type](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_type) is `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`, which means that ***each component*** is an unsigned integer. Thus, you are expected to provide an array of 3 unsigned integers per pixel.

If you want each component to be an unsigned *byte*, then you should use that as your type. And your array should be an array of unsigned bytes.

Comment: Please reply :/ or someone else answer? This is correcting my use of the data parameter, but not solving this issue. Pixels that are not transparent are updated to red. Transparent pixels are still unchangeable.

Comment: Ok, i got it:
GL.TexSubImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, x, y, 1, 1, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Rgba, PixelType.UnsignedByte, new byte[] { color.R, color.G, color.B, 255 });
thanks